# Simple serial communication via USB ports

Tags: c#, arduino

i am new to C#. I want to write a simple console app or function that would open known usb port, for example "COM6" and send pre-configured data through it. Idealy it would work like a somekind od a function sendcommand(command); and int value would be sent. Can someone help me and tell me where to start?

Comment: I will be communicating with arduino

Comment: To start, rather send text. That allows to easily simulate via SerialMonitor. Next, you have two different tasks: 1) sending via Serial Port in .NET 2) receiving in Arduino Serial and how to get an int value from a transmitted line of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow forum is rather for hints on actual programming issues.

"How to get started" is thus off topic.
But as a newbie bonus, here you are:

- In .net ( c# ) you start reading about System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
- In Arduino c++ you start reading about Serial.

Comment: thank, it was not as hard as i thought, everything is working. Now, do you have any suggestions for handshake between arduino and PC?

Comment: That depends on what you want to achieve with that _handshake_. BTW: This is not a chat. Instead of completely rewriting your question, leave this as "solved", and start a new one. Preferably not in the style of  "Any idea how to write good software"?